# how to write a complex query with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

i have a complex query and i try to convert in doctrine with queryBuilder (or at least in DQL) but i don't manage

```
select p.* from Pin p where p.id in 
  (select max(p1.id) from Pin p1 where p1.recipe_id not in
     (select p2.recipe_id from Pin p2 where p2.owner_id=2)
   and p1.visibility = 2 
   and p1.recipe_id in (select recipe_id from recipe where category_id in (1,2))

   group by p1.recipe_id )
```

i try to write it in DQL but i have an error : **Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_IN, got '.'**

```
select p from Pin p where p.id in 
      (select max(p1.id) from Pin p1 where p1.recipe_id not in
         (select p2.recipe_id from Pin p2 where p2.owner_id=2)
       and p1.visibility = 2 group by p1.recipe_id )
    and p.recette.category in :categories
```

Comment: remove .* set just select p

Comment: yes, sorry it was just a mistake, but it is not the reason of the error

Comment: ok, can you put more details about the error message

Comment: as i say i have an error (in Symfony2)  : QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 190: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_IN, got '.'

Comment: You should surround `:categories` with `()`

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have the same error